# Maple, regExp: How to parse "pn2 = -.433222082282652077" into "pn2" and "-0.433222082282652077"?

Tags: regex, math, maple

So I have a string

> pn2 = -.433222082282652077
>   I need to parse it with reg exp into 2 strings (put values into 2 variables)

First A:

> pn2

Second B:

> -0.433222082282652077

How to do such thing with maple?

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression?

Comment: To parse a string... Is there any other way?

Comment: yes, of course there are other ways.  You can write a parser, you could just call `sscanf`, etc. etc. etc.  If you just want to break that string up into pieces, you certainly don't need a regular expression to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try using [Split](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=StringTools/Split)? Use `=` as your separator: `Split(str, "=")`